# Android app-compat Toolbar Styling

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-toolbar

Bigger question I have now, is how do I color the toolbar icons on kitkat / jellybean.  On lollipop I can use the

```
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/ttdPrimaryColor</item>
```

and that seems to do the trip but no such luck on kitkat.

I am trying to figure out how to theme the menu icon on the Toolbar.  I need to keep the title white, but I want the menu icon to be a different color.

This is my current style:

```
 <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

the toolbar looks like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />
```

Another problem is that on most activities I want the drawer toggle to be the apps primary color but on certain activities I want it to be white.  What is the best way to handle that.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Please check this tutorial, this might help you http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Theme for your Activities (not the Toolbar).
Something like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
   <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDrawerArrowToggle"  
          parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
  <item name="color">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```